# Como mostrar emojis en vscode ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vscode

Estoy intentando mostrar los emojis en VSCode desde un equipo con Ubuntu version 20.04, pero al presionar la combinación de tecla 'Windows' + '.' (punto), no realiza ninguna acción ya estuve investigando pero no encontrado nada al respecto que me de una solución, por lo cual aun no logro que se muestren los emojis, no quiero instalar las exenciones en VSCode que por medio de : (dos puntos) te muestra el emoji ya que me causa ruido al programar, cabe mencionar que he probado en el sistema operativo windows y funciona la combinación sin problemas.

Espero y me puedan ayudar si necesito instalar alguna librería extra o si es diferente la combinación de teclas para mostrar los emojis en Ubuntu.

De ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma es descargar la extensión **Emojisense**.

Una vez instalada puedes sacar los emojis con la combinación de teclas **Ctrl + i** o bien **Ctrl + Shift + i**.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).